# how to attach a file in email using phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I want to attach a file (already uploaded from backend) in email sent. But I am having trouble in sending file. I tried the following 2 options but to no avail.

```
1. $mail->addAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" .$file);
2. $mail->addAttachment($file);
```

where $file gives the absolute path to the file(uploads/files/Itineraries/Bhutan/The%20Hidden%20Kingdom%20Trekking%20-%209(days).pdf).
2nd option is working fine in local server but in live server(godaddy.com) it's not working?
Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/" .$file, $name = 'file_name',  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');`

Comment: @Yash No, it's not working.

Comment: @samjhanjoshi What is output showing now ..?

Comment: @Yash, the mail is going fine... only there is no attachment.

Comment: instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/" .$file` give full path like `"http://www.domain.com/upload/file/" .$file`. That actually you can see in url.

Comment: @Yash, No it's not helping either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109220/discussion-between-yash-and-samjhana-joshi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
$file = '/path/to/file/file.zip';

$mail->AddAttachment( $file, 'file.zip' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents("siteURL/foldername/" . $filename), $filename);
```